# sudo apt-get install doesn't work

Tags: raspbian

I installed the POSBox image (I tried v14 and v15) on a Raspberry Pi 3, and everything worked great. Now I would like to use that RPi as a graphic POS, but when I type:

```
sudo apt-get install
```

I get

```
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory)  
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (2: No such file or directory)    
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem but using `sudo` when you are logged in as `root` is redundant.  Did you bother checking whether the paths it says cannot be accessed exist or not?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed something but I think sudo apt-get install, needs to know what to install. sudo apt-get install toilet for example.